# How to build Windows and Mac plugins simultaneously in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-emf, target-platform

After developing the plugin, you must build it for Windows and Mac OS simultaneously during the build process.

I've had no problems developing and building on MacOS so far.
But now we have to build on Windows.

Libraries (e.g. SWT) used when developing on MacOS are available for both Mac and Windows, so plug-ins built on MacOS can also be used on Windows.

However, when building on Windows, there are libraries that exist only on MacOS and not on Windows.

- org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSObject
- org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSString
- org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView
- org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS

Because cocoa is a library for MacOS, even if you add this library to the target platform, Windows will not be able to load this library.

What should I do?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. The plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.swt` is platform-independent, provides the API and requires a platform-specific plugin, or more precisely a fragment/bundle with the platform-dependent implementations. For Windows, for instance, there is the fragment `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64`. If your code depends on one of the mentioned classes like `org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSObject`, you are doing something wrong. In general, your code should not reference anything from another plugin/bundle from a package that has `internal` in its name.

Comment: You should be using [tag:tycho] to do the build, this will choose the correct fragment for each platform. You should not normally be using any of those internal classes - if you are you need to put them in a platform specific plugin or fragment just like SWT does.

Comment: @howlger To build on both MacOS and Windows
I added both org.eclipse.swt.win32 and org.eclipse.swt.cocoa to the target platform.

At this time, we confirmed that only libraries appropriate for the operating system are loaded. To build on both MacOS and Windows
I added both org.eclipse.swt.win32 and org.eclipse.swt.cocoa to the target platform.

At this time, we confirmed that only libraries appropriate for the operating system are loaded. This is exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: @howlger There are libraries for Windows and Mac OS in the target platform path, so I want to load them. You just need to be able to build regardless of execution.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't know what tycho is...

Currently Windows cannot load libraries for macOS and
  An x is appearing. Can this be resolved?

Comment: You will have to learn about tycho. It is not possible to do a single build that runs on all platforms, you need a separate build for each platform which tycho will do for you. tycho will select the appropriate SWT fragments for the different platforms. [tycho tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: @greg-449 I don't think the problem I'm experiencing will be solved with Tycho.

This is because plugins for Windows, Mac, and Linux (Ubuntu) are already built and run normally with my build script.

If this is an issue that needs to be done with Tycho, I think it will only be possible to build for a single platform.

My point is, how do you load libraries for Mac OS on Windows? (I think the question itself makes no sense, but...)

Comment: Tycho will solve your problem because it will not include the macOS components in the build for Windows. (assuming everything has the correct platform rquirements set in the MANIFEST.MF) You cannot run macOS code on Windows.

Comment: @grep-449 So how do I fix the light coming on in Eclipse? Anyway, Eclipse for Windows cannot load libraries for Mac.

Comment: As I already said you have to build separate versions of Eclipse for each platform containing only the plugins for that platform.

Comment: @greg-449 So... in other words, you need to build a separate Eclipse corresponding to the platform.

To build a plug-in for Windows, you need a Windows PC:
You need a Mac to build plugins for Mac.

If so, you must have at least two physical PCs (for different operating systems).

If this is true, do I really need to build it using tycho?

Is it just a maintenance aspect?

Comment: No, tycho can build code for all the platforms on a single machine. It will produce multiple versions of Eclipse targeting the different platforms. So you will get one that will run on Windows, one for macOS Intel, one for macOS Apple Silicon, ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257203/discussion-between-bsjy-and-greg-449).

Comment: @greg-449 So, I understand that tycho is a tool for creating a complete build that runs on multiple platforms. However, when you run Eclipse on Windows and clone a project from git, isn't it natural that an error occurs because the project uses a class like NSObject that is used on Mac? I asked if this could be resolved

Comment: No, as I have already said multiple times you build different versions of Eclipse for different platforms. A plugin that is for macOS should specify that in the MANIFEST.MF and tycho will not include it in builds for other platforms. This is a long established system that Eclipse itself uses to build different versions of SWT for different platforms.

Comment: The project should not use internal classes like `org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSObject`. This is obviously a bug in the code of the project that needs to be fixed on the project side and that have been overlooked all the time until you decided to also support Windows. This is not a build issue, it's a bug in the project in the code you didn't show. You question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), not showing the root problem Y.