# Is there a way to check the Mac version using Platform.OS on Windows?

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, jface, eclipse-emf

In the code I'm currently writing, I've written to provide a buffer to improve drawing performance on MacOS BigSur.

Example code is as follows.

```
class EcoreGridEditPane<PayloadType extends EObject> {
    static val DEFAULT_STYLES = #[
        SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED,
        SWT.BORDER,
        SWT.MULTI,
        SWT.V_SCROLL,
        SWT.H_SCROLL,
        SWT.FULL_SELECTION
    ].reduce[p1, p2|p1.bitwiseOr(p2)];
   // ...

   new(Composite parent, int styles) {
        create(parent, DEFAULT_STYLES.bitwiseOr(styles))
   }
   // ...
   private def create(Composite parent, int styles) {
        fViewer = new TableViewer(parent, styles) => [
            table => [
                layoutData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH)
                
                OSKit.instance.ensureDrawingBuffer(it) // problem in windows os
                headerVisible = true;
                linesVisible = true;
                addListener(SWT.Dispose) [
                    handleDispose()
                ]
            ]
```

### OSKit.xend

```
interface OSKit {
    static def OSKit getInstance() {
        switch Platform.OS {
            case Platform.OS_MACOSX: MacOSKit.instance
            default: CommonOSKit.instance
        }
    }

    def void ensureDrawingBuffer(Control control);

    def boolean isBigSurOrLater();
}
```

### MacOSKit.xtend

```
private def makeBackingLayer(NSView view) {
        if (view.id.performSelector("layer") !== 0L) {
            // Already background layer exist
            return;
        }

        // layer request
        view.id.performSelector("setWantsLayer:", true);

        // layer setting
        val layer = view.id.performSelector("layer");
        layer.performSelector("setContentsFormat:", kCAContentsFormatRGBA8Uint)
    }

    override ensureDrawingBuffer(Control control) {
        control.view.makeBackingLayer()
    }
   
    // ...
    package def Long performSelector(Long receiver, String selector) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver, selector.selectorId)
    }

    package def Long performSelector(Long receiver, String selector, boolean arg1) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver, selector.selectorId, arg1)
    }

    package def Long performSelector(Long receiver, String selector, Long arg1) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver, selector.selectorId, arg1)
    }

    package def Long performSelector(NSObject receiver, String selector) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver.id, selector.selectorId)
    }

    package def Long performSelector(NSObject receiver, String selector, boolean arg1) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver.id, selector.selectorId, arg1)
    }

    package def Long performSelector(NSObject receiver, String selector, Long arg1) {
        return OS.objc_msgSend(receiver.id, selector.selectorId, arg1)
    }
    // ...
```

In this structure, the class called OS is currently org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.

Of course, Windows cannot find the OS class of org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.

So the light comes on in Eclipse for Windows.

Of course, it is understandable that the light indicating an error comes on, and even if the light is displayed, there is no problem with running it at runtime.

However, it is impossible to predict what problems will occur when building this using a build script (Ant) and creating UpdateSite.

Is it possible to add a library for macos (e.g. a Mac-specific JAR such as org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx*) to the target platform used when building on Windows?

Comment: Your platform specific code should be in a platform specific fragment, being used as via an Eclipse extension point or maybe better as an OSGi declarative service. But [as already said to your other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78178179/6505250), stick to the API and do not reference internals from other plugins/bundles. If you have improvements for an open source project that you rely on or use, you should contribute them.

Comment: No, you can't add a mac jar on Windows, it uses native code which is not available in a format that the Windows tools would understand so you won't be able to get it to build. This should be a platform specific fragment.